# Adding Rewrite rule to web.config causes error in IIS console

Tags: iis, web-config, iis-8, http-redirect

Hi I have added a http to https redirect to my web.config

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

It is within the  as required, in fact it is exactly the same as another iis I have running on another box.

However on this server when I save the config and then check the IIS control panel I get an

"There was an error while performing this operation ... Details: Filename \?D:\site\web.config Error:

and there is no error.  When I remove the rewrite from the config everything is fine.

The only difference between this server setup and the one that works is that the broken server website is not in the root or is it the default website.

Has anyone encountered this type of error before?

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 2):

Very strange, even though i had everything set up in IIS and during the add/remove roles to include the http redirect it still needed this extension adding

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=urlrewrite2

the urlrewrite.  I installed that extension and it all started working.  Shame the error message couldnt ell me that i was missing the feature.

Comment: It can't tell you that you are missing a feature. Without the feature installed, all it knows is that there are invalid tags in your web.config file.

Comment: I found this error very unhelpful - it would be much more helpful if it indicated which tags are invalid. It doesn't even give an accurate line number (indicating -1). Also the empty "Config Error" is unfortunate.